# Adding a plugin in vue.js fails

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm having trouble using `vue-litebox` (
https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-litebox), and I'm wondering if it is the component that is behaving odd or if it is me implementing it wrong.

I see this error in the console:

> ```
> [Vue warn]: Method "showLitebox" has already been defined as a data property.
> ```

Here is the sample code from the `vue-litebox` docs:

```
import VueLitebox from 'vue-litebox' 

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: { VueLitebox },
  data: {
      images: [
          '/images/01.png',
          '/images/02.png',
          {
              title: 'My image title',
              src: '/images/03.png'
          }
      ],
      showLitebox: false
  },
  methods: {
      showLitebox() {
          this.showLitebox = true;
      },
      hideLitebox() {
          this.showLitebox = false;
      }
  }
})
```

```
<div id="app">
    <vue-litebox v-if="showLitebox"
        :items="images"
        @close="hideLitebox">
    </vue-litebox>
    <button type="button" @click="showLitebox">Show Litebox</button>
</div>
```

And here is how I implemented it in my custom component:

```
<template>
  <div id>
    <vue-litebox v-if="showLitebox" :items="images" @close="hideLitebox"></vue-litebox>
    <button type="button" @click="showLitebox">Show Litebox</button>
  </div>
</template>


<script>
import VueLitebox from "vue-litebox";

export default {
  components: { VueLitebox },
  data() {
    return {
      images: [
        "https://dummyimage.com/1600/ffffff/000000",
        "https://dummyimage.com/1600/ffffff/000000",
        {
          title: "My image title",
          src: "https://dummyimage.com/1600/ffffff/000000"
        }
      ],
      showLitebox: false
    };
  },
  methods: {
    showLitebox() {
      this.showLitebox = true;
    },
    hideLitebox() {
      this.showLitebox = false;
    }
  }
};
</script> 

<style scoped>
.image {
  float: left;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
  margin: 5px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: And what's the problem? Any error? Describe the odd behavior and what you want instead or it's very hard to help you.

Comment: I got error: "[Vue warn]: Method "showLitebox" has already been defined as a data property."   But my main question is if I wrote the export it in correct way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The console warning indicates that you have defined `showLitebox` more than once in your `<script>`. You've defined `showLitebox` as a data property *and* a method. Rename one of them to fix the issue.

```
data() {
 showLitebox: false,
},
methods: {
 showLitebox() { ... }
}
```

And if you're wondering why the litebox closes upon clicking *next*/*prev*, it's caused by a bug in the component, where it [closes on clicks at its root element](https://github.com/mattbrailsford/vue-litebox/blob/76385f8/src/vue-litebox.vue#L2).

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/j55p2pp63?fontsize=14&module=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponents%2FLiteBox.vue)

Comment: Nice use of the hand emoji!